# How to get a class into the page template for design header?

Tags: theming

In my page-template there is a header, footer and div for the content.

The page-template is used to put menu and footer stuff in that comes back on every page...

But on some pages the header should have a other background... try to realise that with just adding a different class on that header.

But I wonder how I can put a different class on the header in page.html.twig depending on the sort of type content that was used.

Example: So for the home page a created the content type 'home page'...  for the other page i created the content type 'normal page' so how can I put different classes into the page template depending on the content type that created a page?

What is the best way to do this...

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

As you have created new content types, the body tag of your new content type should have a class based on your new content types, like 'node-type-CONTENT_TYPE'. You can use this class to change the background of your footer and header. `.node-type-CONTENT_TYPE .footer`

Comment: Best answer I think... because quick solution... the class is already there... I forgot this! Thanks man! love solutions like this ;-)

Comment: I tried this solution today.. but seems to be there are no classes on the body tag... Can I activate content-type classes on the body tag... or should I install a extra module for that?

Comment: Hi, I added this code to the body tag {{ attributes.addClass(body_classes) }} but the classes don't show up...

Comment: Hm.. this is strange. Did you create custom twig file where you removed the default functionality? The body attributes are defined in the html.html.twig file. Do you have a custom one?